# DIY LED Fixture/Panel Design Questions - 1. How to control each RGB channel (COB) or 2. How to cool a panel of 40 meters of LED strips

Tags: microcontroller, led, pwm, led-driver, diy

I'm looking to build a 1kW LED light fixture for an experimental photographic process.

I need 1kW fixture or around 100,000 lumens because of the low sensitivity of an emulsion.

I'm wondering if someone could give some advice on which would be easier to make
and I'm hoping someone can share with me some solutions for design challenges.

Building an array of 10x 100W COB RGB LEDs:

1. What would be the best way to power the COBs but also, control the brightness and colors?

Could someone recommend a LED driver/powersupply, and board (respectively).
I would like also a way to turn on and off the LEDs for a certain amount of time so that the light can act as shutter (as my large format lenses do not have and shutters - I will be shooting in the dark). I'm told there are custom boards to control LEDs with microcontrollers, or through the DMX512 standard but I'm a bit lost on which are the best, easiest and cheapest options.

2. Is a single 125W TDP CPU fan/heatsink sufficient for cooling (does this make sense)?
3. If the luminous Flux per channel is the following do I consider the lowest value
   when calculating how many COBs I need for the final 100,000 lumens? (***)

R: 1000-2000LM
G: 2000-2400LM
B: 300-400LM ***

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32914506462.html

If building a more traditional (film industry equipment) LED panel:

1. What would be the best way to cool the LED strips while trying to keep the panel as compact as possible (Smallest surface area and having a shape that is as close to a square as possible)?

The initial design idea, from recommendations and research, is to mount the 40 meters of 2835 (120 leds/meter) on an large aluminum plate. Some specifications: ~2500 lumens per meter @ 0.2 watts per LED.

If the "efficiency" of leds to produce light is at the worst 25% @ 1kw power, could I use 8 CPU heatsink fans attached to the back of the aluminum plate?
(750 watts of heat, so use 8x 100W CPU heatsinks/fans?)

I'm leaning towards the COB LEDs, because the photographic process is a color one and to try to get a proper neutral color balance, I've been recommended to use RGB LEDs.
Thought, I think CCT LEDs would work as I can adjust the color Temperature and then use color correcting gels in front of the lens to get fun color casts (think everything looks red, yellow or blue).

If anyone has some experience with these issues/products, I would love and appreciate some advice.

Thank you for reading this.
Be well :)

Best Regards,
Qes

Comment: 100lm/watt would be low efficiency for LEDs.  If you're talking about high power in a small area, pay slightly more and get 150 or 200 lm/watt LEDs.  Factoring in the cheaper driver and reduced need for cooling (and power bill) you might even come out ahead.  Also, don't buy any of this from AliExpress.  Buy from a reputable supplier that has a real spec sheet.

Comment: you need an Arduino and a logic-level mosfet (eg IRLZ44N). An Uno comes with a program called "blink.ino" that you can adjust to turn the LEDs on and off for a set time. Lookup "mosfet as a switch" to find a suitable circuit, but really, for your case, a COB, a FET, and an MCU is likely enough. Don't mess with LED strips, those are inefficient and hog up real-estate. CPU coolers are fine, SSR coolers are cheaper, and heatsinks made for LEDs are easiest. How long is the exposure and how often? If short/sparse ala a flash, you might not even need a heatsink, and you can overdrive the COB 2-4X.

Comment: Thanks user for your reply and advice!
The cheapest option I found for a 500W LED CCT panel is 1800 usd.
It's not so bad but I think if I have a design, my mom's engineer friend can help me put it together.

@dandavis - Hey! Also, thank you so much for your time and advice :)
May I ask for clarification if LED drivers and power supply are made as one unit?

Okay, I will continue to look up the parts you recommended but they seem more advanced than my abilities so far. Okay, no strips. I'm thinking 25% power for focusing, then 1/8th second to 4 seconds for exposure. Thank you!

Comment: Always buy the power supply(s) separate from the LEDs. if you want raw light power, "LED replacement headlight"s will get you cheap lumens, though the color tends towards the cooler end and they don't dim, but 1000s of lumens for $10s. For a higher quality light, use something like https://www.ebay.com/itm/313597049370, which are much better color and available in a couple temps. Those big "DC 12V 70W COB LED Panel Light"s can easily be dimmed and over-run at 100W each for 4 seconds w/o any heatsink, resting say 15-30 seconds between shots, since they have a thick Al backer attached.